# pipenv virtual environment name disappears everytime the VS Code terminal is refreshed

Tags: django, terminal, pipenv, virtual-environment

I was working on a Django project after **activating** the virtual environment created through **pipenv**.

The virtual environment name given in brackets `(lead-manager-full-stack-8btqndKQ)` in the vs code terminal **disappears** everytime i run `python manage.py runserver`
[image]

When i select the powershell as terminal and runs `pipenv shell` again in order to activate the environment again it shows :

> Shell for C:\Users\USER.virtualenvs\lead-manager-full-stack-8btqndKQ
> already activated. No action taken to avoid nested environments.

But it still doesn't show the virtual environment name inside the brackets like it is supposed to show.

Then i tried to run `pipenv shell` in cmd and this time it shows the virtual environment name in bracket in the terminal.
But whenever i reload the terminal or choose new terminal, it doesn't show the virtual environment.

There must be a way to activate the virtual environment at all time, even after reloading the terminal if i am in a folder containing virtual environment right?

Because activating virtual environment everytime i reload the terminal doesn't seem like a good approach.

Comment: Where did you start VS code from? I usually activate my pipenv using `pipenv shell` then start VScode using `code .` from that directory. I never "lose" the env like you're describing.

Comment: i use `code .` from the directory and vs code opens up, and inside vs code i use `pipenv shell`

Comment: See this question: [Pipenv on VSCode: Why is (pipenv) not displayed on the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505757/pipenv-on-vscode-why-is-pipenv-not-displayed-on-the-terminal)

Comment: Also, look bottom left(ish) on the bar and select the python version - make sure it's using the right env for the project!